# JavaScript - how to order firebase data by key of childs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the my firebase data in the following structure:

[image]

I'm querying my data like so:

```
var db_ref = firebase.database().ref('/playlist-data/');
db_ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var artist = childSnapshot.child('artist').val();
     var position = childSnapshot.child('position').val();
     // do something with artist & position
  });
});
```

But I would like to order the returned snapshot data by the key 'position' of each child node of 'playlist-data', so that I have the data in an ascending order. How can I achieve something like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to order by `position`, try the following:

```
db_ref.orderByChild("position").once('value', function(snapshot){
```

from the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild

> `orderByChild`
>
> Generates a new Query object ordered by the specified child key.
>
> Queries can only order by one key at a time. Calling `orderByChild()` multiple times on the same query is an error.

Comment: In this case I have 'n' number of nodes in '/playlist-data'/ and I'm trying to query every node, so I don't know or have the equalTo value

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean now, 
    db_ref.orderByChild('position').once('value', function(snapshot){